# Identifying repeating consecutive digits on the end of a String in haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

So I write a function with the definition

```
getLastDigits :: String -> String
```

which finds repeating digits on the end of a String

So, for example.

```
getLastDigits "1000" should give "000"
getLastDigits "19990299" should give "99"
```

Coming from a java background I'm not quite sure how to structure this program. I'm thinking of using foldr but I'm fairly sure I can't stop the fold half way when the repeating digits end.

**-edit solved. Use the group function.**

Comment: Using group can be very inefficient if you dont reverse the list first. You want something like head $ group $ reverse

Comment: Ok. I see. (SO won't let me post unless I padded the length a bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay then, if it is not homework:

```
lastDigits :: String -> String
lastDigits s = firstDigits . reverse $ s
  where firstDigits :: String -> String
        firstDigits (x:xs) = x : takeWhile (== x) xs
        firstDigits [] = []
```

Comment: `lastDigits'` should really be called `firstDigits` :)

Answer (score 1):

```
import Data.Char (isDigit)

getLastTheSame :: Eq a => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
getLastTheSame pred xs = f (reverse xs)
  where f (y : ys) | pred y = y : takeWhile (== y) ys
        f _                 = []

lastDigits :: String -> String
lastDigits = getLastTheSame isDigit
```

You say you want repeating digits from the end of the string. I presume that if the last character is not a digit then you want the empty string returned.

Recall that `type String = [Char]`.